# How to include child div into parent div automatically?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parent

Is there any way how to add a child div into parent divs. The child div is still same (without changes) but content of parent div is variable. Parent div contains child div automatically like CSS div::before but with whole div in it not just text.

Basically for each parent automatically generate same child.

See figure
[sample of parent and child divs](http://centuryweb.sk/divs.png)

How can I make it via CSS ? (or JS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS cannot generate content (as such) it can only style it.

If the element is not present in the HTML nothing will happen.

It is possible to add "pseudo content" with a pseudo element but the primary purpose of these pseudo-elements is **enhancement** not *addition of "content"*. Also they cannot contain HTML.

It would be possible to use a pseudo element with a bg image in this instance as this is essentially styling.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gu6sm4vr/1/)

```css
div {
    height:250px;
    width:250px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 25px;
    position: relative;    /* required */

}
div:after {
    content:"";
    /* required */
    position: absolute;
    bottom:25px;
    right:25px;
    background-image: url(http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/thumbs/shortcut-arrow.jpg);
    height:75px;
    width:75px;
    background-size:cover;
}

.one {
    background: red;
    width:300px;
}

.two {
    background: lightblue;
    height:300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thx. But how can I add a link to this child (or Can I?)

Comment: You can't add a link to a pseudo-element...it's not a **real** div. As I said, it's **styling**...not content. If you want to add content, you should use Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me what the problem/issue is, but it sounds like you are looking for JS code like this:

```
var child = document.createElement('div');
child.innerHTML = '<p>Child!</p>';

var parent = document.createElement('div');
parent.innerHTML = '<p>Parent 1</p>';

parent.appendChild(child);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your question so I will just give you a solution and then you comment your requirements.

You can have a div that contains another child div which is positioned inside the parent but does not change when you add more content to the parent.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/1fohx3qf/

```
.parent {
border:2px solid black;
padding:5px;
position:relative;
width:124px;
height:120px;
}

.child {
border:2px solid red;
padding:30px;
position:absolute;
bottom:5px;
right:10px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this is just half of it. I need to generate child for each parent automatically. Maybe you have seen somewhere the little arrow under an image eg. to share the picture or somethig like this. See link in the question.

Comment: You want the child to be added to the parent automatically, but how should the parent be added to your system? Will you be adding the parent manually in the HTML? And when will you be adding the parent (example: when a button is clicked)

Comment: Yes, manually. I just wanted to add new stuff without too much styling.